# cefsharp and previewkeydown event not working

Tags: c#, cefsharp

This might be a simple question, but I have a winforms app that is loading a ChromiumWebBrowser control (CefSharp) and I can't figure out how to capture key preview events as they are all being swallowed by the control.

The standard attaching a handler to the PreviewKeyDown event of the browser control isn't working.  Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CEF` is run in it's own message loop, so the standard events don't work.

The first an easiest option is to implement `IKeyboardHandler`, you can check the `CefSharp` source for a more detailed example (there's one that forwards messages to the parent window if required).

Second run with `settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = false`, and call `Cef.DoMessageLoopWork()` on application idle, this will integrate `CEF` into the same message loop as your main application. Again, the source contains examples see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Program.cs#L63

The third option is to hook into the `CEF` message loop, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor.cs for an example

`CEF` = `Chromium Embedded Framework` - `CefSharp` is just a wrapper.

Comment: I tried both options 1 and 3 and while I was able to get the mouse events from the interceptor I wasn't able to capture any keyboard events for some reason.  That being said option 1 worked great, thanks

Comment: Option 1 works for me - thanks (chromiumWebBrowser.KeyboardHandler = new MyKeyboardHandler();)

Answer (score 0):

You can get Keyboard events by setting ChromiumWebBrowser.KeyboardHandler to IKeyboardHandler even multiThreadedMessageLoop = true.

You can do it by implementing interface on form:

```
public partial class WinWebForm : Form, IKeyboardHandler
```

And then assigning it to webbrowser component:

```
webBrowser.KeyboardHandler = this;
```

You need to capture RawKeyDownEvent:

```
public bool OnKeyEvent(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, KeyType type, int windowsKeyCode, int nativeKeyCode, CefEventFlags modifiers, bool isSystemKey)
    {
        if (type == KeyType.RawKeyDown)
        {
```

When you are accessing Form inside OnKeyEvent you need to use
Form.BeginInvoke to ensure you are accessing Form components on right thread:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                                DoZoom(-0.1);
                            }));
```